# What version of MS Exchange supports user picture associated to email messages?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

What version of MS Exchange or Windows Server add support for user picture associated to email messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's supported with at least Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010.